# Creating curved annotations for polygons and lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, annotation, polyline-creation, curved

In general, my problem is that: I can`t display annotations using the option "Using the perimeter (curved)" in QGIS. I tried to solve it in two ways:

1. At first was an attempt to use just a simple placement option "Using the perimeter (curved)" in the polygon layer, but when I chose, I lost annotation on the map.
2. Next step was when I tried to convert polylines into a line and then display my curved annotation, it also didn't work, as my result wasn't a line drawn through the centre of the polygon, but a frame around the polygon?

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

[image: example3]

[image: example4]

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get, what you are trying to achieve. Is this about transformation of feature types, or about labeling? And what role do the centroids play?

Comment: The problem arises when I want to display the annotation with the placement - using perimeter(curved)

Comment: Which problem do you experience?

Comment: I'm losing my annotation when I switch to "using perimeter(curved)"! You can see it on the new scrinshorts!

Comment: Am I correctly understanding you: you have converted your polygons to polylines and now trying to achieve the same labelling technique that was previously used for polygons, but now labels are not visible when you chose `'Using perimeter (curved)'` for polylines? Are you sure that even enclosed polylines have something to with **"perimeter"**? Apparently, I do not have that option `'Using perimeter (curved)'` for polylnes in both QGIS2 and QGIS 3.